# jquery - expand google map when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have split page - on one side i have sections with texts, on the other i have google map with location the refer to the texts.

I add script that expand the map height when you scroll down, but it's not so intuitive.

Is there any better code than can open expand the map while user scroll down?

This is my current code:

```
// change map size when scroll down
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 450) {
        $("#map-warp").addClass("change-map-canvas");   // removed the . from class
        $("#map-warp").css("margin-top", "40px"); ;     // change margin from top for close infoWindow button
    } else {
        $("#map-warp").removeClass("change-map-canvas");  // removed the . from class
        $("#map-warp").css("margin-top", "10px"); ;
    }
});
```

Comment: so you want actually when page scroll start the map position remain same right?

Comment: @Dipakchavda well, when user scroll down i would like the map to start grow until it will get to full height. and i also need it to flow down (like now)